# PHP inserting only 10 rows to Mysql via a foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I am stuck while inserting data to my mysql table using a foreach loop to insert multiple rows at a time.

```
foreach($event as $booking){
    
    $startDate = $booking[DTSTART];
    $checkIn = strtotime($startDate[value]);
    
    $check_in = date("Y-m-d", $checkIn);
    
    $endDate = $booking[DTEND];
    $checkOut = strtotime($endDate[value]);
    
    $check_out = date("Y-m-d", $checkOut);
    
    $booking_source = "Airbnb";
    
    $source_id = "2";
    
    $summary = $booking[SUMMARY];
    
    $description = $booking[DESCRIPTION];
    
    $uid = $booking[UID];
    
    $sql = "INSERT INTO test_ics (uid, check_in, check_out, summary, description, source, source_id) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            
    $result = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $result->bind_param('sssssss', $uid, $check_in, $check_out, $summary, $description, $booking_source, $source_id);
    $result->execute();
    echo "<br>";
    echo "$check_in";
}
```

The code is working fine and inserting all the rows when I remove `description` and `summary` fields from the table where both of them are `VARCHAR(2550)` but when I am trying to run the code to insert rows with `description` and `summary` (like it is in the code above) its inserting only 10 rows.

Thanks

> Notice: Use of undefined constant DTSTART - assumed 'DTSTART' in /home/fadipro/public_html/admin/get-airbnb-bookings.php on line 40
>
> Notice: Use of undefined constant value - assumed 'value' in /home/fadipro/public_html/admin/get-airbnb-bookings.php on line 41
>
> Notice: Use of undefined constant DTEND - assumed 'DTEND' in /home/fadipro/public_html/admin/get-airbnb-bookings.php on line 45
>
> Notice: Use of undefined constant value - assumed 'value' in /home/fadipro/public_html/admin/get-airbnb-bookings.php on line 46
>
> Notice: Use of undefined constant SUMMARY - assumed 'SUMMARY' in /home/fadipro/public_html/admin/get-airbnb-bookings.php on line 54
>
> Notice: Use of undefined constant DESCRIPTION - assumed 'DESCRIPTION' in /home/fadipro/public_html/admin/get-airbnb-bookings.php on line 56
>
> Notice: Use of undefined constant UID - assumed 'UID' in /home/fadipro/public_html/admin/get-airbnb-bookings.php on line 58

Comment: Best guess is that there is some character in description or summary which is causing the query to fail. To monitor that in the foreach check the status of the sql insertion and if it fails in an array push the error message and print that array after the foreach. You can then check the exact cause and then fix it accordingly...

Comment: Hard to know really unless we can see the value of `$event`. How many records are you expecting to be inserted?

Comment: `VARCHAR(2550)` :/ just use `TEXT`

Comment: Add a `var_dump($event);` to check the values. Maybe the summary/desc is bigger than you table field?

Comment: I am expecting around 30 records and I can see all of them in `var_dump` as well as `echo();` but it can't get inserted in mysql

Comment: My point is if I get any error, why its running for exactly 10 records each time?

Comment: add `error_reporting(E_ALL|E_NOTICE);` in front of your script to see errors.

Comment: "why its running for exactly 10 records each time"...probably because the 11th one fails.

Comment: `$result = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $result->bind_param('sssssss', $uid, $check_in, $check_out, $summary, $description, $booking_source, $source_id);
    $result->execute();`...any one of these three statements could fail and return `false` (or throw an exception, depending on your config) but you don't seem to be testing any of them (and then checking the value of `$conn->error`), either that or you're suppressing exceptions somewhere

Comment: `any one of these three statements could fail and return false (or throw an exception, depending on your config)` how can I test these statements or how can I configure my code to get the error message because my error_log is not showing any error? Please guide.

Comment: Which db layer are you using? mysqli or PDO?

Comment: @Adder I am using mysqli

Comment: Please check the edit. I have added the error I am getting but not quite sure what it means.

Comment: `$startDate = $booking[DTSTART];` -> add single quotes -> `$startDate = $booking['DTSTART'];` and the same for the line after. That is the notice.

Comment: `"any one of these three statements could fail and return false...how can I test these statements"` ...well, by checking whether they return false or not. Sorry, I thought that would be fairly obvious? If they return false, then output the value of `$conn->error` to find the underlying error message. But like I said, depending on your config, they may throw an exception on failure instead. I don't know how you've got it set up.

Comment: Anyway, per the warnings you've got above, `$booking[DTSTART];` should be `$booking["DTSTART"];` etc. Otherwise it tries to look for a constant with that name to use as the index of the array, instead of treating it as a string.

Comment: Chances are this might fix the DB issue as it'll send the right data to the database instead.

Comment: No if you omit the quotes, it will trigger a notice, and then treat it as a string. So it does not affect behaviour.

Comment: @Adder the issue was there in my sourc of DATA. Actually, `DESCRIPTION` was not set in each row so I was getting `FATAL ERROR`. I have set `$description` to NULL and added an `if(isset)` statement to check if its set. Now my code is working fine. Thanks for your help. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the notices by putting the string indexes in quotes like e.g. this `$booking['DTSTART']`.

To catch the database errors, I assume you are using exceptions to report them. This code catches and prints the exception:

```
    try {
        $result = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $result->bind_param('sssssss', $uid, $check_in, $check_out, $summary, $description, $booking_source, $source_id);
        $result->execute();
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

My guess is it will reveal data that is too long for the column.

Answer (score 1):

If your fields name is not constant then you have to write it with single quotes

```
foreach($event as $booking){
  $startDate = $booking['DTSTART'];
  $checkIn = strtotime($startDate['value']);

  $check_in = date("Y-m-d", $checkIn);

  $endDate = $booking['DTEND'];
  $checkOut = strtotime($endDate['value']);

  $check_out = date("Y-m-d", $checkOut);

  $booking_source = "Airbnb";

  $source_id = "2";

  $summary = $booking['SUMMARY'];

  $description = $booking['DESCRIPTION'];

  $uid = $booking['UID'];

  $sql = "INSERT INTO test_ics (uid, check_in, check_out, summary, description, source, source_id) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

  $result = $conn->prepare($sql);
  $result->bind_param('sssssss', $uid, $check_in, $check_out, $summary, $description, $booking_source, $source_id);
  $result->execute();
  echo "<br>";
  echo "$check_in";
}
```

Comment: perhaps worth highlighting exactly what you changed? It may not be immediately obvious to the reader. Also you missed some (value, UID) so I've altered that, and corrected your formatting error. And actually double or single quotes would be fine here, the important thing is to turn it from a constant into a string.

Comment: Hi @ADyson thanks for your help but the issue was in the file I am getting data from. Actually, `DESCRIPTION` was not available in all the rows and also it was `NULL` in some of the rows that's why I was getting the errors. I have added `NULL` as default value in my DB and also added `if(isset)` in my PHP to fix the issue. Thanks anyways for your help.

Comment: @RajanBenipuri No problem. But my advice was relevant. If you'd been checking SQL errors you'd have spotted that earlier because SQL would have told you that you couldn't insert a NULL value into that field. And it seems I was correct in assuming that a particular row (or rows) was at fault, hence why it added 10 and then stopped.

Comment: Indeed your advice was relevant and useful at the same time. Thanks